# Perl LWP::UserAgent simulate browser

Tags: perl, web-scraping, webbrowser-control, lwp-useragent

I am trying to automate getting web page using LWP::UserAgent but I get 403 Forbidden error while if I use from console wget https://dreaminislam.com/a/ or curl I get the page normal. How to set the correct options for LWP::UserAgent to get that page and similar to simulate real browser. Here is sample code.

```
use HTTP::CookieJar::LWP ();
use LWP::UserAgent;
use LWP::Simple;

    my $url = qq{https://dreaminislam.com/a/};
    my $content = getUrl($url);
    exit;

sub getUrl {

    my $url = shift;
    my $jar = HTTP::CookieJar::LWP->new;
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(timeout => 180,  cookie_jar => $jar, protocols_allowed => ['http', 'https']);
    $ua->agent(qq{Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0});

    my $response = $ua->get($url);

    if ($response->is_success) {
        my $content = $response->decoded_content;
        return $content;
    } else {
        my $content = $response->decoded_content;
        printf "Get url error [%d] %s.\n", $response->code, $response->message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, what differences are there between the request?

Comment: LWP doesn't run JavaScript, but your browser does.

Comment: @ikegami wget and curl works return normal response while LWP returns 403 Forbidden.

Comment: What differences are there between the **requests**? (Not the responses)

Comment: @ikegami not sure I understand your question, I explained everything I am doing in the post. the  wget https://dreaminislam.com/a/  and  curl https://dreaminislam.com/a/  works from the console normal but the LWP code above gives  403 Forbidden and I am asking how to setup LWP to work like wget and curl.

Comment: LWP and wget are obviously sending different HTTP requests to the server if they are getting different responses from the server. What are those HTTP requests? You can't hope to reconcile the differences between the requests until you determine what those differences are!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there is some Anti-Bot protection installed at this site. It seems to require at least a `User-Agent` and a `Accept` header:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();

my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'https://dreaminislam.com/a/');
$req->header('User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0');
$req->header('Accept' => '*/*');
my $response = $ua->request($req);

die $response->code if ! $response->is_success;
print $response->decoded_content;
```