# How to set a custom User-Agent in Perl's Selenium::Remote::Driver

Tags: selenium, perl, user-agent

I use Selenium::Remote::Driver and need to set up a "normal" user-agent. I've tried to use Selenium::UserAgent, but it has only some User-Agents for mobiles and tables, and none for usual desktop PC's. Maybe there's a way to expand the list of devices in Selenium::UserAgent, or how to set up a correct User-Agent (I'd like would be Firefox) in Selenium::Remote:Driver manually?

Update:

I'm trying to parse a website which is protected from bots (solve the puzzle if you are a human). When I try to parse it with the default Selenium+Firefox UserAgent - the protection appears.

I've tried to use Selenium::UserAgent and it worked - the protection has disappeared, but I wasn't able to scrape the needed data, because the target site promotes it's mobile apllication instead of showing the needed data this way.

So, after that I've checked the UserAgent of my home computer's browser and set it up using LWP::UserAgent:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0" );

my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new( browser_name => 'firefox', ua => $ua );
```

But this way the protection arrived again.

After that, I've connected to my server through the VNC viewer, opened the same Firefox I've been using with Selenium, and there was no anti-bot protection this way. So, that's why I'm sure that I need to use a correct UserAgent and/or some other settings.

Comment: To clarify your question can you show some sample code? See [mcve] for more information

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57856721/perl-lwpuseragent-simulate-browser

Comment: @HåkonHægland Looks like the Accept header is what I need, but how to set it up in my situation?